# Using Myhill Nerode to prove that a language is not regular

Tags: finite-automata

Prove that the language $A$ on $\{0,1\}$ containing all words for which the number of $0$s is equal to the number of $1$s is not regular.

I know one way to do it would be to show that the cardinality of $A / \mathbin \equiv$ is infinite. But how would I find the different equivalence classes and then show it has an infinite number of equivalence classes?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66433612/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136104/755 (see the original version on CS.SE).  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be your language and let $\equiv$ be the equivalence relation defined by $x \equiv y$ iff $x \in \Sigma^*$ and $y \in \Sigma^*$ have no distinguishing extension (a distinguishing extension is a word $z \in \Sigma^*$ such that exactly one of $xz$ and $yz$ belongs to $L$).

Given $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$ with $i < j$, $0^i$ and $0^j$ cannot belong the same equivalence class since $1^i$ is a distinguishing extension for them: $0^i 1^i \in L$ but $0^j 1^i \not\in L$.

This shows that $L/\mathbin\equiv$ is not finite, and hence $L$ is not regular.

Comment: Wouldnt this be the proof for {0^n1^n}? Or does this proof work for my question too?

Comment: This proof is specifically for $\{0^n1^n\}$ but can be easily extended to the language in the question. Simply replace $1^i$ with any word $s$, and argue that if $s$ is a distinguishing extension then $i = \#_1(s) - \#_0(s) = j$, in contradiction that $i\neq j$

Comment: Ok, so the proof would go like this: Let the starting letter of the string be 0^i. For any 0^i and 0^j, there cannot exist a single extension s such that 0^is=0^js. So, let us say s=0^m1^m+i. This wouldn't satisfy 0^j because 0^j+m1^m+i would not belong to A. So there are infinitely many distinct extensions for strings.

Comment: @nirshahar This proof is not specifically for $\{0^n 1^n\}$. It shows that the language containing all words with the same number of zeros and ones induces an infinite number of equivalence classes, implying that it is not regular. It does so by exhibiting an infinite set of elements that must all belong to different classes, namely all words of the form $0^i$. To show that two words cannot be in the same equivalence class it suffices to provide *any* distinguishing extension. There is no need to argue about all of them. The one I'm using to distinguish $0^i$ from some other $0^j$ is $1^i$.

Comment: Oh right, you are correct.